# jquery validate and php captcha issue

Tags: php, jquery

my captcha field

```
<p style="height:30px;"><img id="captcha" src="includes/secureimage/securimage_show.php?sid=<?php echo md5(time()); ?>" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
<a tabindex="-1" style="border-style: none; margin-left:5px;" href="#" title="Refresh Image" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'includes/secureimage/securimage_show.php?sid=' + Math.random(); return false"><img src="images/refresh.png" alt="Reload Image" onclick="this.blur()" style="vertical-align: top; border:0;" /></a></p></div>
<p><label for="seccode">Verification Code:<span class="important">*</span></label><input id="seccode" type="text" name="seccode" size="10" class="required" /></p>
```

my jquery validate plugin code for captcha

```
seccode: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
        url: "checkuser.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
        seccode: function() {
            //alert($("#seccode").val());
            return $("#seccode").val();
        }
    }
}
}
```

my php

```
if($_POST['seccode'])
    {
        $securimage = new Securimage();
        return $securimage->check($_POST['seccode']);
    }
```

i am using securimage for captcha. message for required condition for captcha is working. but remote condition is not working. Ofcourse i have included required class file in php and also started session_start() in the start of php file.

[note]
the error gone now. something new comes now. First time the captcha works when i focus out, but after that it continues to callback the validation method on each change.. see the firebug output below...

```
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=pzubwg
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=pzubwg

200 OK
        36ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=l
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=l

200 OK
        39ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=ln
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=ln

200 OK
        41ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnr
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnr

200 OK
        36ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrg
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrg

200 OK
        38ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgu
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgu

200 OK
        32ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgue
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgue

200 OK
        25ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgu
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgu

200 OK
        34ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrg
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrg

200 OK
        40ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgv
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgv

200 OK
        42ms    
jquery.min.js (line 140)
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgve
GET http://localhost:8080/property/html/captcha.php?seccode=lnrgve

200 OK
        37ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically when your jquery validates the captcha code, the captcha code is destroyed in the very same function where the validation occurs. Thats why i was getting the problem. The code works fine once you refresh the captcha again.

Answer (score 1):

Validation requires you to return "true" if the remote validation was successful, also I prefer using different server-side checking for remote validations just like this [demo](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#The_Remember_The_Milk_sign-up_form).

So the captcha validation will be, `post_captcha.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();
if ($securimage->check($_POST['seccode']) == false) {
    // the code was incorrect
    // handle the error accordingly with your other error checking
    // or you can do something really basic like this
    //die('The code you entered was incorrect.  Go back and try again.');
    echo "false";
} else {
    echo "true";
}
?>
```

Open the demo link and with your firebug enabled and only submit the username field with any username and then check it with one of the taken usernames (for e.g. "*asdf*"), you will notice that the responses it just like my `post_captcha.php` responses!

Ibrahim

Comment: ok i created another file captcha.php, i entered the above code there, but it keeps on giving me false always. i checked the session vlaues and they are right on their place. what can be the problem then

Comment: can you setup a test page? or paste your form and captcha.php files on http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: here is the form
http://pastebin.com/AH8UtVs5
here is the captcha.php
http://pastebin.com/Gnnp9YVy
here is the jquery
http://pastebin.com/FwNQAWHd

Comment: your code seems to work just fine man, I've made an example on my host [here](http://enblogopedia.com/project/securimage/form.php) I've disabled username and email remote checking and used include_once in the captcha post file and it's working just fine!

Comment: Also, I've added these two line to the securimage_show.php file: `$img->perturbation = 0.1;` and `$img->num_lines = 0;` to make the captcha more visible for testing purposes

Comment: what about the firebug output? If i enter the code wrong, error comes on focus out. so far so good. after that whatever the code is, it does not accept the code again until i refresh the captcha. I dont know what is going wrong? may be jquery

Comment: ok i have done with that error too... what about the following error when i start typing on required fields?
[QUOTE]The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless[/QUOTE]

Comment: start typing!!!, are you using any other jQuery plugin? maybe jQueryUI auto-complete?  now the focus out is when the validation plugin kicks on (other than submitting the form of course)