# jQuery validation + Securimage issue

Tags: php, validation, jquery, captcha

I have some strange issue using [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validate) plugin. Firs of all here is my code:

`formvalid.js`

```
var v = jQuery("#sendform").validate({
        rules: {
            /* some other rules */
            captcha: {
                required: true,
                remote: "securimage/process.php"
            }
        },            
        messages: {
            /* some other messages */
            captcha: {
        required:"Security code is required",
        remote:"Security code is incorrect!"
        }
        }
    });
```

`process.php`

```
<?php
/* I tried with and without session_start(). 
Both ways works with same probelm (read next)*/
//session_start();
include_once '../securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_GET['captcha']) == false) 
    echo "false";

else
    echo "true";
?>
```

`sendform.php`

```
<?php
include_once 'securimage/securimage.php';

//echo $_POST['captcha'];

$securimage = new Securimage();
//echo "<br/>".$securimage->getCode();

if($_POST['captcha'] && $securimage->check($_POST['captcha']))
{
    //do sending
}
?>
```

So, the problem is when I'm checking `security code` with AJAX request, ajax works fine, but when I'm send the form, `$securimage->check($_POST['captcha'])` in `sendform.php` returns `false`. Then I tried to disable remote capctha validation and viola `$securimage->check($_POST['captcha'])` in `sendform.php` returned `true`!

As you can see I `echo` some values in `sendform.php` and result is:

#### Case #1: AJAX captcha validation *enabled*.

Results:

```
echo $_POST['captcha'];               // User_input_value;
echo $securimage->getCode();          // nothing
$securimage->check($_POST['captcha']) // false
```

#### Case #2: AJAX captcha validation *disabled*.

Results:

```
echo $_POST['captcha'];               // User_input_value;
echo $securimage->getCode();          // code from image
$securimage->check($_POST['captcha']) // true (if equals)
```

Anyone know how to make it work?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533670/jquery-validate-and-php-captcha-issue/4534565#4534565) was asked a while ago, it seems that the captcha is resetting after each check.

What I suggest is to have a flag in your session that you would set to `TRUE` in your `process.php` after a valid captcha and then checking it instead of `$securimage->check($_POST['captcha'])` in your `sendform.php`:

```
if ($securimage->check($_GET['captcha']) == false) {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = FALSE;
    echo "false";
} else {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = TRUE;
    echo "true";
}
```

And:

```
if($_POST['captcha'] && isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']) // set it back to false inside this!
```

Now here are two notes:

- Since you are having two separate calls, some one can still change the captcha between the two calls
- Since it's only a captcha and you most probably is using it to prevent spam, I wouldn't bother using the technique I posted above! actually I wouldn't even bother doing another captcha check in the `sendform.php`

Of course someone could spam you, but then and if you really need to use Ajax, then you have to stop processing the captcha in the jQuery plugin and just validate it when you submit your form, just like the original [documentation](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/php-ajax-captcha/) approach.

Comment: Thank you for advice! The funny thing is that when jQ calls `process.php` (no matter how many times) it is not reset captcha! But when I check captcha after submit form it's return nothing... I'm already did like in your second note for now. And the main point: to prevent spam you have to do serverside validation, because spam bots doesn't use any JS, they are using server directly...

Answer (score 2):

To prevent resetting captch, you should validate yourself without calling check() function in process.php like below code

```
<?php
include_once 'securimage.php';
if(!isset($_GET['txtcaptcha']))
    return 'false';


$securimage = new Securimage();
$securecode = $securimage->getCode();

if (strtolower($securecode) != strtolower($_GET['txtcaptcha'])) 
    echo "false";

else
    echo "true";
?>
```